# Replacing NA values with a calculation result added on to the previous column

Tags: r, for-loop, time, replace, missing-data

I have a response time data set called `Ambulance`

```
Date      Station TOC        ORD       MOB       IA        LS        AH       
01/01/13   S1     00:02:44   00:04:11  00:04:44  00:04:58  00:05:12  00:05:32
01/01/13   S2     00:03:04   00:03:21  00:03:54  00:04:28  00:04:52  00:05:02
01/01/13   S4     00:04:24   00:04:41  N/A       00:05:18  00:05:22  00:05:35
01/01/13   S1     00:04:44   00:04:51  00:05:04  00:05:58  00:06:12  00:06:32
```

The time data represents a different stage of the emergency response process so the column to the right will always be at a later point in the day. The data set is quite large 22,000 records and lots of `NA`'s, but in some cases there is only one per row meaning it is not that much of a problem.

I have normalised the data by converting the time to seconds using `lubridate::hms`. I want to replace the missing values for "MOB" for example, by taking the mean of a newly calculated field `Emergency$ORD-IA` and adding it to the "ORD" value but I am lost at how to do it. I need the loop to through each row and add the mean value onto the column before the `NA` value I think.

This is my first post here so all help greatly appreciated!

```
dput(head(Ambulance, 20))
```

structure(list(Date = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("01/01/2013", 
"01/01/2014", "01/01/2015", "01/02/2013", "01/02/2014", "01/02/2015", 
"01/03/2013", "01/03/2014", "01/03/2015", "01/04/2013", "01/04/2014", 
"01/04/2015", "01/05/2013", "01/05/2014", "01/05/2015", "01/06/2013", 
"01/06/2014", "01/06/2015", "01/07/2013", "01/07/2014", "01/07/2015", 
"01/08/2013", "01/08/2014", "01/08/2015", "01/09/2013", "01/09/2014", 
"01/09/2015", "01/10/2013", "01/10/2014", "01/10/2015", "01/11/2013", 
"01/11/2014", "01/11/2015", "01/12/2013", "01/12/2014", "01/12/2015", 
"02/01/2013", "02/01/2014", "02/01/2015", "02/02/2013", "02/02/2014", 
"02/02/2015", "02/03/2013", "02/03/2014", "02/03/2015", "02/04/2013", 
"02/04/2014", "02/04/2015", "02/05/2013", "02/05/2014", "02/05/2015", 
"02/06/2013", "02/06/2014", "02/06/2015", "02/07/2013", "02/07/2014", 
"02/07/2015", "02/08/2013", "02/08/2014", "02/08/2015", "02/09/2013", 
"02/09/2014", "02/09/2015", "02/10/2013", "02/10/2014", "02/10/2015", 
"02/11/2013", "02/11/2014", "02/11/2015", "02/12/2013", "02/12/2014", 
"02/12/2015", "03/01/2013", "03/01/2014", "03/01/2015", "03/02/2013", 
"03/02/2014", "03/02/2015", "03/03/2013", "03/03/2014", "03/03/2015", 
"03/04/2013", "03/04/2014", "03/04/2015", "03/05/2013", "03/05/2014", 
"03/05/2015", "03/06/2013", "03/06/2014", "03/06/2015", "03/07/2013", 
"03/07/2014", "03/07/2015", "03/08/2013", "03/08/2014", "03/08/2015", 
"03/09/2013", "03/09/2014", "03/09/2015", "03/10/2013", "03/10/2014", 
"03/10/2015", "03/11/2013", "03/11/2014", "03/11/2015", "03/12/2013", 
"03/12/2014", "03/12/2015", "04/01/2013", "04/01/2014", "04/01/2015", 
"04/02/2013", "04/02/2014", "04/02/2015", "04/03/2013", "04/03/2014", 
"04/03/2015", "04/04/2013", "04/04/2014", "04/04/2015", "04/05/2013", 
"04/05/2014", "04/05/2015", "04/06/2013", "04/06/2014", "04/06/2015", 
"04/07/2013", "04/07/2014", "04/07/2015", "04/08/2013", "04/08/2014", 
"04/08/2015", "04/09/2013", "04/09/2014", "04/09/2015", "04/10/2013", 
"04/10/2014", "04/10/2015", "04/11/2013", "04/11/2014", "04/11/2015", 
"04/12/2013", "04/12/2014", "04/12/2015", "05/01/2013", "05/01/2014", 
"05/01/2015", "05/02/2013", "05/02/2014", "05/02/2015", "05/03/2013", 
"05/03/2014", "05/03/2015", "05/04/2013", "05/04/2014", "05/04/2015", 
"05/05/2013", "05/05/2014", "05/05/2015", "05/06/2013", "05/06/2014", 
"05/06/2015", "05/07/2013", "05/07/2014", "05/07/2015", "05/08/2013", 
"05/08/2014", "05/08/2015", "05/09/2013", "05/09/2014", "05/09/2015", 
"05/10/2013", "05/10/2014", "05/10/2015", "05/11/2013", "05/11/2014", 
"05/11/2015", "05/12/2013", "05/12/2014", "05/12/2015", "06/01/2013", 
"06/01/2014", "06/01/2015", "06/02/2013", "06/02/2014", "06/02/2015", 
"06/03/2013", "06/03/2014", "06/03/2015", "06/04/2013", "06/04/2014", 
"06/04/2015", "06/05/2013", "06/05/2014", "06/05/2015", "06/06/2013", 
"06/06/2014", "06/06/2015", "06/07/2013", "06/07/2014", "06/07/2015", 
"06/08/2013", "06/08/2014", "06/08/2015", "06/09/2013", "06/09/2014", 
"06/09/2015", "06/10/2013", "06/10/2014", "06/10/2015", "06/11/2013", 
"06/11/2014", "06/11/2015", "06/12/2013", "06/12/2014", "06/12/2015", 
"07/01/2013", "07/01/2014", "07/01/2015", "07/02/2013", "07/02/2014", 
"07/02/2015", "07/03/2013", "07/03/2014", "07/03/2015", "07/04/2013", 
"07/04/2014", "07/04/2015", "07/05/2013", "07/05/2014", "07/05/2015", 
"07/06/2013", "07/06/2014", "07/06/2015", "07/07/2013", "07/07/2014", 
"07/07/2015", "07/08/2013", "07/08/2014", "07/08/2015", "07/09/2013", 
"07/09/2014", "07/09/2015", "07/10/2013", "07/10/2014", "07/10/2015", 
"07/11/2013", "07/11/2014", "07/11/2015", "07/12/2013", "07/12/2014", 
"07/12/2015", "08/01/2013", "08/01/2014", "08/01/2015", "08/02/2013", 
"08/02/2014", "08/02/2015", "08/03/2013", "08/03/2014", "08/03/2015", 
"08/04/2013", "08/04/2014", "08/04/2015", "08/05/2013", "08/05/2014", 
"08/05/2015", "08/06/2013", "08/06/2014", "08/06/2015", "08/07/2013", 
"08/07/2014", "08/07/2015", "08/08/2013", "08/08/2014", "08/08/2015", 
"08/09/2013", "08/09/2014", "08/09/2015", "08/10/2013", "08/10/2014", 
"08/10/2015", "08/11/2013", "08/11/2014", "08/11/2015", "08/12/2013", 
"08/12/2014", "08/12/2015", "09/01/2013", "09/01/2014", "09/01/2015", 
"09/02/2013", "09/02/2014", "09/02/2015", "09/03/2013", "09/03/2014", 
"09/03/2015", "09/04/2013", "09/04/2014", "09/04/2015", "09/05/2013", 
"09/05/2014", "09/05/2015", "09/06/2013", "09/06/2014", "09/06/2015", 
"09/07/2013", "09/07/2014", "09/07/2015", "09/08/2013", "09/08/2014", 
"09/08/2015", "09/09/2013", "09/09/2014", "09/09/2015", "09/10/2013", 
"09/10/2014", "09/10/2015", "09/11/2013", "09/11/2014", "09/11/2015", 
"09/12/2013", "09/12/2014", "09/12/2015", "10/01/2013", "10/01/2014", 
"10/01/2015", "10/02/2013", "10/02/2014", "10/02/2015", "10/03/2013", 
"10/03/2014", "10/03/2015", "10/04/2013", "10/04/2014", "10/04/2015", 
"10/05/2013", "10/05/2014", "10/05/2015", "10/06/2013", "10/06/2014", 
"10/06/2015", "10/07/2013", "10/07/2014", "10/07/2015", "10/08/2013", 
"10/08/2014", "10/08/2015", "10/09/2013", "10/09/2014", "10/09/2015", 
"10/10/2013", "10/10/2014", "10/10/2015", "10/11/2013", "10/11/2014", 
"10/11/2015", "10/12/2013", "10/12/2014", "10/12/2015", "11/01/2013", 
"11/01/2014", "11/01/2015", "11/02/2013", "11/02/2014", "11/02/2015", 
"11/03/2013", "11/03/2014", "11/03/2015", "11/04/2013", "11/04/2014", 
"11/04/2015", "11/05/2013", "11/05/2014", "11/05/2015", "11/06/2013", 
"11/06/2014", "11/06/2015", "11/07/2013", "11/07/2014", "11/07/2015", 
"11/08/2013", "11/08/2014", "11/08/2015", "11/09/2013", "11/09/2014", 
"11/09/2015", "11/10/2013", "11/10/2014", "11/10/2015", "11/11/2013", 
"11/11/2014", "11/11/2015", "11/12/2013", "11/12/2014", "11/12/2015", 
"12/01/2013", "12/01/2014", "12/01/2015", "12/02/2013", "12/02/2014", 
"12/02/2015", "12/03/2013", "12/03/2014", "12/03/2015", "12/04/2013", 
"12/04/2014", "12/04/2015", "12/05/2013", "12/05/2014", "12/05/2015", 
"12/06/2013", "12/06/2014", "12/06/2015", "12/07/2013", "12/07/2014", 
"12/07/2015", "12/08/2013", "12/08/2014", "12/08/2015", "12/09/2013", 
"12/09/2014", "12/09/2015", "12/10/2013", "12/10/2014", "12/10/2015", 
"12/11/2013", "12/11/2014", "12/11/2015", "12/12/2013", "12/12/2014", 
"12/12/2015", "13/01/2013", "13/01/2014", "13/01/2015", "13/02/2013", 
"13/02/2014", "13/02/2015", "13/03/2013", "13/03/2014", "13/03/2015", 
"13/04/2013", "13/04/2014", "13/04/2015", "13/05/2013", "13/05/2014", 
"13/05/2015", "13/06/2013", "13/06/2014", "13/06/2015", "13/07/2013", 
"13/07/2014", "13/07/2015", "13/08/2013", "13/08/2014", "13/08/2015", 
"13/09/2013", "13/09/2014", "13/09/2015", "13/10/2013", "13/10/2014", 
"13/10/2015", "13/11/2013", "13/11/2014", "13/11/2015", "13/12/2013", 
"13/12/2014", "13/12/2015", "14/01/2013", "14/01/2014", "14/01/2015", 
"14/02/2013", "14/02/2014", "14/02/2015", "14/03/2013", "14/03/2014", 
"14/03/2015", "14/04/2013", "14/04/2014", "14/04/2015", "14/05/2013", 
"14/05/2014", "14/05/2015", "14/06/2013", "14/06/2014", "14/06/2015", 
"14/07/2013", "14/07/2014", "14/07/2015", "14/08/2013", "14/08/2014", 
"14/08/2015", "14/09/2013", "14/09/2014", "14/09/2015", "14/10/2013", 
"14/10/2014", "14/10/2015", "14/11/2013", "14/11/2014", "14/11/2015", 
"14/12/2013", "14/12/2014", "14/12/2015", "15/01/2013", "15/01/2014", 
"15/01/2015", "15/02/2013", "15/02/2014", "15/02/2015", "15/03/2013", 
"15/03/2014", "15/03/2015", "15/04/2013", "15/04/2014", "15/04/2015", 
"15/05/2013", "15/05/2014", "15/05/2015", "15/06/2013", "15/06/2014", 
"15/06/2015", "15/07/2013", "15/07/2014", "15/07/2015", "15/08/2013", 
"15/08/2014", "15/08/2015", "15/09/2013", "15/09/2014", "15/09/2015", 
"15/10/2013", "15/10/2014", "15/10/2015", "15/11/2013", "15/11/2014", 
"15/11/2015", "15/12/2013", "15/12/2014", "15/12/2015", "16/01/2013", 
"16/01/2014", "16/01/2015", "16/02/2013", "16/02/2014", "16/02/2015", 
"16/03/2013", "16/03/2014", "16/03/2015", "16/04/2013", "16/04/2014", 
"16/04/2015", "16/05/2013", "16/05/2014", "16/05/2015", "16/06/2013", 
"16/06/2014", "16/06/2015", "16/07/2013", "16/07/2014", "16/07/2015", 
"16/08/2013", "16/08/2014", "16/08/2015", "16/09/2013", "16/09/2014", 
"16/09/2015", "16/10/2013", "16/10/2014", "16/10/2015", "16/11/2013", 
"16/11/2014", "16/11/2015", "16/12/2013", "16/12/2014", "16/12/2015", 
"17/01/2013", "17/01/2014", "17/01/2015", "17/02/2013", "17/02/2014", 
"17/02/2015", "17/03/2013", "17/03/2014", "17/03/2015", "17/04/2013", 
"17/04/2014", "17/04/2015", "17/05/2013", "17/05/2014", "17/05/2015", 
"17/06/2013", "17/06/2014", "17/06/2015", "17/07/2013", "17/07/2014", 
"17/07/2015", "17/08/2013", "17/08/2014", "17/08/2015", "17/09/2013", 
"17/09/2014", "17/09/2015", "17/10/2013", "17/10/2014", "17/10/2015", 
"17/11/2013", "17/11/2014", "17/11/2015", "17/12/2013", "17/12/2014", 
"17/12/2015", "18/01/2013", "18/01/2014", "18/01/2015", "18/02/2013", 
"18/02/2014", "18/02/2015", "18/03/2013", "18/03/2014", "18/03/2015", 
"18/04/2013", "18/04/2014", "18/04/2015", "18/05/2013", "18/05/2014", 
"18/05/2015", "18/06/2013", "18/06/2014", "18/06/2015", "18/07/2013", 
"18/07/2014", "18/07/2015", "18/08/2013", "18/08/2014", "18/08/2015", 
"18/09/2013", "18/09/2014", "18/09/2015", "18/10/2013", "18/10/2014", 
"18/10/2015", "18/11/2013", "18/11/2014", "18/11/2015", "18/12/2013", 
"18/12/2014", "18/12/2015", "19/01/2013", "19/01/2014", "19/01/2015", 
"19/02/2013", "19/02/2014", "19/02/2015", "19/03/2013", "19/03/2014", 
"19/03/2015", "19/04/2013", "19/04/2014", "19/04/2015", "19/05/2013", 
"19/05/2014", "19/05/2015", "19/06/2013", "19/06/2014", "19/06/2015", 
"19/07/2013", "19/07/2014", "19/07/2015", "19/08/2013", "19/08/2014", 
"19/08/2015", "19/09/2013", "19/09/2014", "19/09/2015", "19/10/2013", 
"19/10/2014", "19/10/2015", "19/11/2013", "19/11/2014", "19/11/2015", 
"19/12/2013", "19/12/2014", "19/12/2015", "20/01/2013", "20/01/2014", 
"20/01/2015", "20/02/2013", "20/02/2014", "20/02/2015", "20/03/2013", 
"20/03/2014", "20/03/2015", "20/04/2013", "20/04/2014", "20/04/2015", 
"20/05/2013", "20/05/2014", "20/05/2015", "20/06/2013", "20/06/2014", 
"20/06/2015", "20/07/2013", "20/07/2014", "20/07/2015", "20/08/2013", 
"20/08/2014", "20/08/2015", "20/09/2013", "20/09/2014", "20/09/2015", 
"20/10/2013", "20/10/2014", "20/10/2015", "20/11/2013", "20/11/2014", 
"20/11/2015", "20/12/2013", "20/12/2014", "20/12/2015", "21/01/2013", 
"21/01/2014", "21/01/2015", "21/02/2013", "21/02/2014", "21/02/2015", 
"21/03/2013", "21/03/2014", "21/03/2015", "21/04/2013", "21/04/2014", 
"21/04/2015", "21/05/2013", "21/05/2014", "21/05/2015", "21/06/2013", 
"21/06/2014", "21/06/2015", "21/07/2013", "21/07/2014", "21/07/2015", 
"21/08/2013", "21/08/2014", "21/08/2015", "21/09/2013", "21/09/2014", 
"21/09/2015", "21/10/2013", "21/10/2014", "21/10/2015", "21/11/2013", 
"21/11/2014", "21/11/2015", "21/12/2013", "21/12/2014", "21/12/2015", 
"22/01/2013", "22/01/2014", "22/01/2015", "22/02/2013", "22/02/2014", 
"22/02/2015", "22/03/2013", "22/03/2014", "22/03/2015", "22/04/2013", 
"22/04/2014", "22/04/2015", "22/05/2013", "22/05/2014", "22/05/2015", 
"22/06/2013", "22/06/2014", "22/06/2015", "22/07/2013", "22/07/2014", 
"22/07/2015", "22/08/2013", "22/08/2014", "22/08/2015", "22/09/2013", 
"22/09/2014", "22/09/2015", "22/10/2013", "22/10/2014", "22/10/2015", 
"22/11/2013", "22/11/2014", "22/11/2015", "22/12/2013", "22/12/2014", 
"22/12/2015", "23/01/2013", "23/01/2014", "23/01/2015", "23/02/2013", 
"23/02/2014", "23/02/2015", "23/03/2013", "23/03/2014", "23/03/2015", 
"23/04/2013", "23/04/2014", "23/04/2015", "23/05/2013", "23/05/2014", 
"23/05/2015", "23/06/2013", "23/06/2014", "23/06/2015", "23/07/2013", 
"23/07/2014", "23/07/2015", "23/08/2013", "23/08/2014", "23/08/2015", 
"23/09/2013", "23/09/2014", "23/09/2015", "23/10/2013", "23/10/2014", 
"23/10/2015", "23/11/2013", "23/11/2014", "23/11/2015", "23/12/2013", 
"23/12/2014", "23/12/2015", "24/01/2013", "24/01/2014", "24/01/2015", 
"24/02/2013", "24/02/2014", "24/02/2015", "24/03/2013", "24/03/2014", 
"24/03/2015", "24/04/2013", "24/04/2014", "24/04/2015", "24/05/2013", 
"24/05/2014", "24/05/2015", "24/06/2013", "24/06/2014", "24/06/2015", 
"24/07/2013", "24/07/2014", "24/07/2015", "24/08/2013", "24/08/2014", 
"24/08/2015", "24/09/2013", "24/09/2014", "24/09/2015", "24/10/2013", 
"24/10/2014", "24/10/2015", "24/11/2013", "24/11/2014", "24/11/2015", 
"24/12/2013", "24/12/2014", "24/12/2015", "25/01/2013", "25/01/2014", 
"25/01/2015", "25/02/2013", "25/02/2014", "25/02/2015", "25/03/2013", 
"25/03/2014", "25/03/2015", "25/04/2013", "25/04/2014", "25/04/2015", 
"25/05/2013", "25/05/2014", "25/05/2015", "25/06/2013", "25/06/2014", 
"25/06/2015", "25/07/2013", "25/07/2014", "25/07/2015", "25/08/2013", 
"25/08/2014", "25/08/2015", "25/09/2013", "25/09/2014", "25/09/2015", 
"25/10/2013", "25/10/2014", "25/10/2015", "25/11/2013", "25/11/2014", 
"25/11/2015", "25/12/2013", "25/12/2014", "25/12/2015", "26/01/2013", 
"26/01/2014", "26/01/2015", "26/02/2013", "26/02/2014", "26/02/2015", 
"26/03/2013", "26/03/2014", "26/03/2015", "26/04/2013", "26/04/2014", 
"26/04/2015", "26/05/2013", "26/05/2014", "26/05/2015", "26/06/2013", 
"26/06/2014", "26/06/2015", "26/07/2013", "26/07/2014", "26/07/2015", 
"26/08/2013", "26/08/2014", "26/08/2015", "26/09/2013", "26/09/2014", 
"26/09/2015", "26/10/2013", "26/10/2014", "26/10/2015", "26/11/2013", 
"26/11/2014", "26/11/2015", "26/12/2013", "26/12/2014", "26/12/2015", 
"27/01/2013", "27/01/2014", "27/01/2015", "27/02/2013", "27/02/2014", 
"27/02/2015", "27/03/2013", "27/03/2014", "27/03/2015", "27/04/2013", 
"27/04/2014", "27/04/2015", "27/05/2013", "27/05/2014", "27/05/2015", 
"27/06/2013", "27/06/2014", "27/06/2015", "27/07/2013", "27/07/2014", 
"27/07/2015", "27/08/2013", "27/08/2014", "27/08/2015", "27/09/2013", 
"27/09/2014", "27/09/2015", "27/10/2013", "27/10/2014", "27/10/2015", 
"27/11/2013", "27/11/2014", "27/11/2015", "27/12/2013", "27/12/2014", 
"27/12/2015", "28/01/2013", "28/01/2014", "28/01/2015", "28/02/2013", 
"28/02/2014", "28/02/2015", "28/03/2013", "28/03/2014", "28/03/2015", 
"28/04/2013", "28/04/2014", "28/04/2015", "28/05/2013", "28/05/2014", 
"28/05/2015", "28/06/2013", "28/06/2014", "28/06/2015", "28/07/2013", 
"28/07/2014", "28/07/2015", "28/08/2013", "28/08/2014", "28/08/2015", 
"28/09/2013", "28/09/2014", "28/09/2015", "28/10/2013", "28/10/2014", 
"28/10/2015", "28/11/2013", "28/11/2014", "28/11/2015", "28/12/2013", 
"28/12/2014", "28/12/2015", "29/01/2013", "29/01/2014", "29/01/2015", 
"29/03/2013", "29/03/2014", "29/03/2015", "29/04/2013", "29/04/2014", 
"29/04/2015", "29/05/2013", "29/05/2014", "29/05/2015", "29/06/2013", 
"29/06/2014", "29/06/2015", "29/07/2013", "29/07/2014", "29/07/2015", 
"29/08/2013", "29/08/2014", "29/08/2015", "29/09/2013", "29/09/2014", 
"29/09/2015", "29/10/2013", "29/10/2014", "29/10/2015", "29/11/2013", 
"29/11/2014", "29/11/2015", "29/12/2013", "29/12/2014", "29/12/2015", 
"30/01/2013", "30/01/2014", "30/01/2015", "30/03/2013", "30/03/2014", 
"30/03/2015", "30/04/2013", "30/04/2014", "30/04/2015", "30/05/2013", 
"30/05/2014", "30/05/2015", "30/06/2013", "30/06/2014", "30/06/2015", 
"30/07/2013", "30/07/2014", "30/07/2015", "30/08/2013", "30/08/2014", 
"30/08/2015", "30/09/2013", "30/09/2014", "30/09/2015", "30/10/2013", 
"30/10/2014", "30/10/2015", "30/11/2013", "30/11/2014", "30/11/2015", 
"30/12/2013", "30/12/2014", "30/12/2015", "31/01/2013", "31/01/2014", 
"31/01/2015", "31/03/2013", "31/03/2014", "31/03/2015", "31/05/2013", 
"31/05/2014", "31/05/2015", "31/07/2013", "31/07/2014", "31/07/2015", 
"31/08/2013", "31/08/2014", "31/08/2015", "31/10/2013", "31/10/2014", 
"31/10/2015", "31/12/2013", "31/12/2014", "31/12/2015"), class = "factor"), 
    Station.Area = structure(c(16L, 17L, 7L, 17L, 17L, 16L, 16L, 
    17L, 17L, 3L, 17L, 7L, 7L, 3L, 13L, 16L, 17L, 8L, 8L, 8L), .Label = c("Balbriggan", 
    "Blanchardstown", "Dolphins Barn", "Donnybrook", "Dun Laoghaire", 
    "Dunshaughlin", "Finglas", "Kilbarrack", "MH14", "MH17", 
    "North Strand", "Phibsborough", "Rathfarnham", "Skerries", 
    "Swords", "Tallaght", "Tara St"), class = "factor"), Clinical.Status = structure(c(12L, 
    4L, 9L, 4L, 2L, 9L, 15L, 9L, 7L, 4L, 9L, 9L, 2L, 9L, 12L, 
    7L, 7L, 9L, 9L, 4L), .Label = c("A", "Alpha", "B", "Bravo", 
    "BRAVO", "C", "Charlie", "D", "Delta", "E", "Echo", "Non ProQa Class", 
    "Not Classed", "O", "Omega"), class = "factor"), TOC = c(129, 
    161, 832, 418, 896, 990, 913, 1785, 2198, 1985, 2529, 2536, 
    2657, 3285, 3520, 3546, 3958, 4100, 4166, 4177), ORD = c(254, 
    881, 986, 1353, 1405, 1590, 1750, 2007, 2347, 2545, 2657, 
    2681, 2835, 3498, 3633, 3728, 4103, 4141, 4291, 4344), MOB = c(298, 
    904, 1011, 1379, 1415, 1736, 1753, 2131, 2424, 2553, 2693, 
    2771, 2855, 3557, 3659, 3744, 4187, 4200, 4368, 4438), IA = c(616, 
    1090, 1506, 2088, 1645, 2171, NA, 2508, 2892, 3085, 3023, 
    3120, 3229, 3786, 4106, NA, 4652, 4538, 4561, 5099), LS = c(NA, 
    NA, 1776, NA, 2359, 2639, NA, NA, 3335, 3750, NA, NA, 3462, 
    4551, NA, 4725, 5222, 4942, 5420, 5786), AH = c(NA, NA, 2255, 
    NA, NA, 3283, 2575, 2966, NA, NA, NA, 3867, NA, 4799, NA, 
    5314, 5477, 5233, 5854, 6066), MAV = c(1667, 1252, 2509, 
    2601, 3937, 4969, 3107, 3718, 4021, 4737, 3289, 4722, 4647, 
    6291, 4376, 5641, 6287, 4470, 6422, 7616), CD = c(1764, 1367, 
    2835, 2658, 4335, 5750, 3633, 3729, 4141, 5077, 3498, 5159, 
    5440, 6392, 4483, 5705, 6735, 6918, 6456, 7942), TOC_ORD = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_), ORD_MOB = c(44, 23, 25, 26, 10, 146, 3, 124, 77, 
    8, 36, 90, 20, 59, 26, 16, 84, 59, 77, 94), MOB_IA = c(318, 
    186, 495, 709, 230, 435, NA, 377, 468, 532, 330, 349, 374, 
    229, 447, NA, 465, 338, 193, 661), IA_LS = c(NA, NA, 270, 
    NA, 714, 468, NA, NA, 443, 665, NA, NA, 233, 765, NA, NA, 
    570, 404, 859, 687), LS_AH = c(NA, NA, 479, NA, NA, 644, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 248, NA, 589, 255, 291, 434, 
    280), AH_MAV = c(NA, NA, 254, NA, NA, 1686, 532, 752, NA, 
    NA, NA, 855, NA, 1492, NA, 327, 810, -763, 568, 1550), MAV_CD = c(97, 
    115, 326, 57, 398, 781, 526, 11, 120, 340, 209, 437, 793, 
    101, 107, 64, 448, 2448, 34, 326)), .Names = c("Date", "Station.Area", 
"Clinical.Status", "TOC", "ORD", "MOB", "IA", "LS", "AH", "MAV", 
"CD", "TOC_ORD", "ORD_MOB", "MOB_IA", "IA_LS", "LS_AH", "AH_MAV", 
"MAV_CD"), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")

Answer (score 0):

Here is one option that reshapes your data from wide to long format, before we use `zoo::na.approx` to linearly approximate missing values.

Replace `"N/A"` values with proper `NA` and save the relevant column names (and their order).

```
Emergency[Emergency == "N/A"] <- NA
col_names <- names(Emergency)
```

The first step is to create an `idx` column that we'll use in `arrange` and later to have a unique identifier when we `spread` the data back into wide format.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(zoo)
Emergency %>% 
  mutate(idx = row_number()) %>% 
  gather(key, time, TOC:AH) %>% 
  arrange(idx, Station) %>% 
  mutate(date_time = as.POSIXct(paste(Date, time),
                                format = "%d/%m/%y %H:%M:%S")) %>% 
  mutate(date_time = as.POSIXct(na.approx(date_time),
                                origin = '1970-01-01 00:00.00 UTC')) %>% 
  mutate(time = format(date_time, "%H:%M:%S")) %>% #format() gives character
  select(-date_time) %>% 
  spread(key, time) %>% 
  arrange(idx) %>% 
  select(col_names)
#      Date Station      TOC      ORD      MOB       IA       LS       AH
#1 01/01/13      S1 00:02:44 00:04:11 00:04:44 00:04:58 00:05:12 00:05:32
#2 01/01/13      S2 00:03:04 00:03:21 00:03:54 00:04:28 00:04:52 00:05:02
#3 01/01/13      S4 00:04:24 00:04:41 00:04:59 00:05:18 00:05:22 00:05:35
#4 01/01/13      S1 00:04:44 00:04:51 00:05:04 00:05:58 00:06:12 00:06:32
```

You don't need the 3 `mutate` calls and if you want to keep the data in long format the part starting from `spread(...)` is optional.

Note that creating the `date_time` column is necessary because all your cols from `TOC` to `AH` are character.

**data**

```
Emergency <- structure(list(Date = c("01/01/13", "01/01/13", "01/01/13", "01/01/13"
), Station = c("S1", "S2", "S4", "S1"), TOC = c("00:02:44", "00:03:04", 
"00:04:24", "00:04:44"), ORD = c("00:04:11", "00:03:21", "00:04:41", 
"00:04:51"), MOB = c("00:04:44", "00:03:54", NA, "00:05:04"), 
    IA = c("00:04:58", "00:04:28", "00:05:18", "00:05:58"), LS = c("00:05:12", 
    "00:04:52", "00:05:22", "00:06:12"), AH = c("00:05:32", "00:05:02", 
    "00:05:35", "00:06:32")), .Names = c("Date", "Station", "TOC", 
"ORD", "MOB", "IA", "LS", "AH"), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Hmm when I applied it I got the following error: Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Column `date_time` must be length 1324968 (the number of rows) or one, not 0
In addition: Warning message:
attributes are not identical across measure variables;
they will be dropped

Comment: Can you add a more realistic example? Post the output of `dput(head(Emergency, 20))` at the end of your question.

Comment: I was trying to make my data seem simpler in the initial example, I hope this makes it clearer. Essentially I have created new columns that measure the distance in time between each column. I want to take the mean value of this newly created column, in the first instance it will be TOC_ORD (bear in mind I have already converted it all to seconds) and add this mean value onto the TOC value that come before the NA value in ORD, because the ORD value is always going to be a later point in time. Does this make sense?

Comment: This is the solution I needed, eventually figured it out. Thanks for your help and apologies for the teething problems with posting!

    Toc_MOB_mean <- mean(New_ambulance$TOC_MOB)
    for (i in 1:220828){
      if(is.na(New_ambulance$ORD[i])){
        New_ambulance$ORD[i] = New_ambulance$TOC[i]+Toc_MOB_mean